# Matching Multiple Criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, matching

I am trying to index the `Implant Duration` in Data Set A by matching the `Sensor ID` and `Visit` in Data Set B to the `Sensor ID` and `Visit` in Data Set A. I have already tried using `=INDEX($L$3:$L$8,MATCH(1,($K$3:$K$8=O3)*($J$3:$J$8=N3),0),1)` as an array folumla (holding Ctrl + Shift + Enter) but it returns `#N/A`. Here is just a small sample of the data I am trying to apply this match/index formula to.

[image]

Just to clarify a bit, `Implant Duration` in Data Set B should read:

```
1
2
1
2
3
```

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't simply use `=N3` in cell P3 and copy down?  Is there ever a difference between visit number and implant duration?

Comment: There is a difference between implant duration and visit. For example, a sensor could have been inserted on Visit 3, meaning it has an implant duration of 1. I now realize that the sample data I chose doesn't show any variance between implant duration and visit. I will try that method @pnuts, thanks!